# Neo4j Cypher query on Rest returns 500 response

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I try to send a simple Cypher query to neo4j 2.1.3 and get a 500 response:

`POST : http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher`

```
data = {
  "query" : "MATCH (it) return it limit 10"
   }
```

Tried different variations of including the following header:

```
   {'content-type': 'application/json',"Accept": 'application/json'}
```

All resulted in the same 500 http response.

Btw .. Regular Rest API requests such as : `http://localhost:7474/db/data/node` works just fine..

Comment: can you share the exact code you used to send that http request?

Comment: also can you check the data/log/neo4j.log file for an error message?

Comment: there is no code... I just tried a POST request using 'postman' . and there are no traces of it in the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was in the encoding of the data.
Not sure exactly what, but I found it in [neo4j-rest-client code](https://github.com/versae/neo4j-rest-client/blob/master/neo4jrestclient/request.py) .

There is an encoding function. Used that and everything works.

```
def _json_encode( data, ensure_ascii=False):

 def _any(data):
    ret = None
    if isinstance(data, (list, tuple)):
        ret = _list(data)
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        ret = _dict(data)
    elif isinstance(data, decimal.Decimal):
        ret = str(data)
    elif isinstance(data, datetime.time):
        ret = data.strftime(options.TIME_FORMAT)
    else:
        ret = data
    return ret

 def _list(data):
    ret = []
    for v in data:
        ret.append(_any(v))
    return ret

 def _dict(data):
    ret = {}
    for k, v in data.items():
        # Neo4j doesn't allow 'null' properties
        if v is not None:
            ret[k] = _any(v)
    return ret
 ret = _any(data)
 return json.dumps(ret, ensure_ascii=ensure_ascii)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% but AFAIK http headers are case sensitive, so try to use `Content-Type` instead of `content-type`. If you still get a 500, inspect `data/log` and/or `data/graph.db/messages.log` for any helpful entries.

Comment: HTTP headers should not be case sensitive http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2 . The rest sounds good though :)

Comment: @JohnMark13: you're right. skme: try to trace the full request and response (including headers) you're sending over the wire.

Comment: I have, and tried all the options capital letters or not. When eliminating the content type, I get a 415 response, so I guess it does accept the header. As I mentioned above, nothing can be found in the logs